# Pandas Plotting Legend and Colormap Question (Much Appreciated)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, group-by

Data:

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    #Data creation
    d1 = pd.DataFrame({"Date" : ['1/1/2022', '12/15/2010', '6/1/2015', '1/31/2022', '12/31/2010', '3/10/2009', '1/7/2022', '12/9/2010','12/20/2010','1/13/2022'],
               "Item": ['Food', 'Food', 'Gasoline', 'Coffee', 'Coffee', 'PayPal', 'Gasoline', 'Gasoline','Gasoline','Coffee'],
               "Price": [3.89, 7.00, 11, 0.99, 8.01, 99, 76, 50,48,9]})

    # Change Date column to datetime
    d1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(d1['Date'])

    # Create MMM-YY column from Date column
    d1['MMM-YY'] = d1['Date'].dt.strftime('%b') + '-' + d1['Date'].dt.strftime('%y')

    #Sort DataFrame by Date
    d1.sort_values('Date', inplace=True)

    #Groupy by MMM-YY, Item and sum Price
    d1_sorted = d1.groupby(['MMM-YY','Item'], sort = False)[['Price']].sum()

    d1_sorted

                      Price
    MMM-YY  Item    
    Mar-09  PayPal    99.00
    Dec-10  Gasoline  98.00
            Food       7.00
            Coffee     8.01
    Jun-15  Gasoline  11.00
    Jan-22  Food       3.89
            Gasoline  76.00
            Coffee     9.99
```

I'm using the following line of code to plot the data:

```
    d1_sorted.unstack().plot(kind = 'bar', title = 'Total Expense', stacked = True, figsize = (15,10), colormap = 'Blues')
```

Output:

[image]

I have three questions:

1. What is the "None,Item" line in the legend, and how can I get rid of it?
2. How can I get the legend to only show the values in the second column ("Item") of the grouping? For example, I want the legend to say "PayPal" and "Gasoline", instead of the tuple-like "(Price, PayPal)" and "(Price, Gasoline)".
3. I want the graph colors to be similar to those in the graph (blue theme), but one of the colors is too light. Can I shift the color spectrum of a default colormap such as 'blues' to make the light color darker? Any recommendations besides default colormaps for a noob like me who is intimidated by colormaps? I would also appreciate any resources on learning more about colors.

Answer (score 0):

```
d1_sorted.unstack().droplevel(level=0,axis=1).plot(kind = 'bar', title = 'Total Expense', stacked = True, figsize = (15,10), colormap = 'Pastel2')
```

1 and 2. Remove multiIndex with droplevel.

3. Not sure how to adjust the range on the colorscale within the a bar plot. I would consider using a discrete colormap.